# Forward cookies between servers for authentication

Tags: rest, security, authentication, saml

I need to analyze the following authentication scenario.

There are three systems involved:

- List item
- System "A" is a client-side web application. It communicates with its back-end via REST.
- System "B" is a server-side web application (JSF). It needs to access A's back-end via REST.
- An Identity Provider, which is used to authenticate users for both systems.
  All systems are deployed to different servers/domains.

System "A" uses SAML 2.0 to authenticate users through the Identity Provider. When an user is authenticated, it creates a user session and maps it to the user's browser via cookies. Any subsequent REST call carries the user's cookies.

System "B" also uses the same Identity Provider for authentication. B's back-end needs to call A's back-end via REST. It must authenticate "under the hood", without user interaction. I'm in charge of the development of this system. Now the questions:

- Can I retrieve, from "System B" side, the browser cookies set by "System A"?
- Assuming I can retrieve them: if I forward them in my REST calls, will it be enough to authenticate?
- Do you see any other solution? (must not require the user to login again)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like a question for [Software Engineering SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) in my opinion

Comment: @alteredinstance when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 0):

I typically solve this kind of problems in one of following ways.
Option 1: Token exchange. Convert SAML token to JWT, and send JWT to backend.
Option 2: SAML token propagation. Send SAML to backend, and have backend to accept SAML as authentication token.
In the implementation, front end map cookie to either SAML token, or build JWT from cookie/saml.